# Unity-Vuforia Multiple screen space canvas issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, render, tracking, vuforia

I'm trying tu make appear description in the screen space for each image target I got and let and extended tracking for letting the info stay between the changing of two image target...
I succeed to do that for one canvas, I read the infos staying on the screen, but when I put two canvas in my screen, the detection start blinking and the infos doesn't stay, It blinks for the two canvas...

Answer (score 0):

i suppose from your question that you have a description associated with each image target so

what if you make that description a child to the image target, hence it will appear with it

or

you make one canvas and some kind of manager to that canvas and in case of image target detection you place the appropriate content on the canvas

here is an example script you need to attach to the image target [Source](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-play-audio-when-targets-get-detected)

```
public class ImageTargetDetection : MonoBehaviour,
                                        ITrackableEventHandler
{
private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

void Start()
{
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }
}

public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
        // target is found
    }
    else
    {
        // target is lost
    }
}   
}
```